# Blender Grease Pencil - key frame animation is continuous instead of frame by frame

Tags: grease-pencil, 2d

[image]

Please see the image below..I have onion skinning and auto-keying turned off, I should note. I have tried opening a new file with auto-keying turned on and do not seem to have this problem. I know it is possible to animate 2d with auto-keying off so I just can't figure out why my key frames stack on top of one another rather than transitioning frame by frame.

Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Every new keyframed drawing or editing turns off the previous one in the same drawing layer. As you're drawing in different layers, previous ones are unaffected.

To solve you can either:

- draw the new pose in the same layer of the previous to be replaced (standard method)
- or, if you prefer, add an empty keyframe in the previous layer when it has to be turned off.